# Go importing legacy repository in indirect

Tags: git, go, goimports

So I have this multi-repo project and am planning to almost remake it from ground up, just keeping the features I think are useful, so I decided to clone the code to new repositories with clean commit history.

The **legacy** project was organized like this:

- https://github.com/org/legacy-core: Core project, references both utils and engine.
- https://github.com/org/legacy-utils: Reusable functions like logging and magefiles.
- https://github.com/org/legacy-engine: Some functions to handle multi threading. Uses utils repository.

I first tried cloning these 3 code bases into 3 newer repositories:

- https://github.com/org/new-core
- https://github.com/org/new-utils
- https://github.com/org/new-engine

I then released a v0.0.1 of them just so I could point the go.mod to the correct "new" versions using replace like this:

`replace github.com/org/legacy-utils v1.0.0 => github.com/org/new-utils v0.0.1`

This is my local file tree:

```
❯ tree
.
├── new-core
├── new-utils
├── new-engine
```

Unfortunately, *replace* didn't worked as I expected, and some parts of the inner references of *new* repositories still points to the *legacy* in runtime, the legacy project will be removed further on so this could not happen.

Trying to figure out why, I decided to rename all imports in the files of all three projects using [go-imports-rename](https://github.com/sirkon/go-imports-rename) and point them to the correctly newer versions.

I then removed the go.mod and go.sum, ran:

- `go clean -modcache`
- `go mod init github.com/org/new-...`

for the three repos respectively.

Commited and re-released a newer **v0.0.1** pre-release version of utils and engine. This is where things got weird...

Although I don't have ANY reference to the legacy repositories in the new-utils, the new-engine still tells me that the legacy-utils is a indirect import in new-utils.

my go.mod of the engine looks like this:

```
module github.com/org/new-engine

go 1.20

require (
    github.com/org/new-utils v0.0.1
    ... // omitted some extra imports
)

require (
    github.com/org/legacy-utils v1.0.0 // indirect
)
```

It should not have any reference to the legacy repositories.

Since this is a private project of the company I currently work on, I can't give any specific info about the project itself.

Comment: Without a [mre] we are only left to guess. `replace` can only work from the current module, which means for anything other than tests it’s only used for building `main` when declared in main’s module. The legacy import path must be referenced somewhere, but we cannot find it for you.

Comment: Fair enough. I did search for any import to the old legacy modules in the projects. I'll try to reproduce the error in my own account and edit the question using my example.

Comment: Oh, make sure you didn’t clone the old tags too into the new repos, that is going to cause those old commits to still get queried as legitimate versions with the old names in the wrong repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based in the last comment by @JimB.

I decided to check on all the tags in my repos. I deleted all new releases and tags, reexecuted `go clean -modcache` and checked the GOPATH pkg folders if there were some cached stuff.

Removed go.sum and go.mod for both utils and engine.

Re-executed the go mod init and executed `go get` to the correct private versions before running `go mod tidy`.

This way the imports got right and I was able to push to the main branch and use those imports correctly in my core project.

Thank you @JimB